# Component communication over shared service

Tags: angular

What if you are in one component, and you want to trigger method from another component? You can achieve this on three other ways, read more on this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkPbz.png). Here I want to show you, the simplest possible example of how to achieve this.

[image]

Let's say we have 2 components that need to communicate through a shared service. Let's say that we are in Navigation Component and we want to trigger method from the Main component.

Comment: Nice. What is exactly your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Go to **Navigation Component** and create a method that reference
>   shared service.

```
import { SharedService } from 'app/services/sharedService.service';
constructor(private service: SharedService){}

      // Say Hello from another component
      SayHello(message) {
        this.service.CallComponentMethod(message);
      }
```

> Now open **Angular Service** and create Subject and method for publishing
>   subject.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'; // don't forget to import it!
public pushMessage = new Subject<any>();

  CallComponentMethod(message) {
    this.pushMessage.next(message);
  }
```

*More about subjects you can read on this [page][2].*

> Now open **Main Component** and subscribe subject from shared service.

```
import { SharedService } from 'app/services/sharedService.service';
constructor(private service: SharedService){}

this.service.pushMessage.subscribe((x) => {
  console.log('This is a message sent from the navigation component: ' + x);
});
```